# How to get Thread Run Time by the Thread ID?

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting

i have to code a concurrent merge sort application with 5 Threads and my problem is that every mergesort Thread shall output the consumed time for the sorting process. Is there anyway that i can do it using the thread id?

For example

sorting: [125000;249999] in 1138.921ms

Answer (score 0):

For every thread, before calling merge sort take system time by System.currentTimeMillis(). Similarily after finishing merge sort again take system time. Calculate the difference. This will be time taken by each thread.